# MVC design pattern for the Presentation Layer in 3 layer architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, 3-tier, presentation-layer

I currently have a web application that is based upon a 3 Tier architecture. I wish to change my Presentation layer from using Web Forms to MVC4.

Now I have done some research and from what I read I understood that the View represents the .aspx of a Web Form. The Controller represents the Code Behind (.cs) of a Web Form.

The problem that I have is that I do not see any use for the Model. This is because I can directly call methods from the Business Logic Layer directly from the Controller making the purpose of the Model useless.

Is there something that I am misunderstanding? If so what are you views on implementing an MVC design patter for the presentation layer in a 3 layer architecture?

Comment: Please have a look for more details https://www.robustbase.com/2018/09/model-view-controller-design-pattern.html?m=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple application the model in MVC can simply be the DTOs from the Application or Business Layer. In this case you're right, you probably don't need a separate model in the UI.